# Structure of query does not match function result type in plpgsql function

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

```
CREATE 
OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.sp_production_snapshot(periodid integer, flagdc integer) RETURNS TABLE(
  prod_period_id integer, 
  period character varying, 
  nosp character varying, 
  policy_no character varying, 
  policy_name character varying, 
  status_id integer, 
  pol_status character varying, 
  family_bisnis character varying, 
  tahun_ke integer, 
  year_comm integer, 
  payment integer, 
  plan_code character varying, 
  life_premium double precision, 
  rider_premium double precision, 
  extra_premium double precision, 
  total_premium double precision, 
  mop integer, 
  ccy_code character varying, 
  ccy_rate double precision, 
  post_date date, 
  commence_date date, 
  issue_date date, 
  stream_start_date date, 
  due_date date, 
  app_code character varying, 
  policy_cat character varying, 
  apcrd_a_amt double precision, 
  apcrd_b_amt double precision, 
  apcrd_d_amt double precision, 
  fyip_credit_amt double precision, 
  comm_npk_id integer, 
  comm_npk integer, 
  comm_npk_name character varying, 
  comm_rank_id integer, 
  comm_rank_code integer, 
  comm_rank_name character varying, 


) LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $function$ BEGIN RETURN QUERY . . . . . . . . .

;
```

When I'm running it like this:

```sql
select * from sp_production_snapshot(865, 1);
```

I get the error:

```
SQL Error [42804]: ERROR: structure of query does not match function result type
  Detail: Returned type bigint does not match expected type integer in column 1.
  Where: PL/pgSQL function sp_production_snapshot(integer,integer) line 3 at RETURN QUERY
```

What is wrong with my script? I just migrated from gorm v1 to gorm v2. Before everything was fine, but many things break after moving to gorm v2.

Comment: "Returned type bigint does not match expected type integer in column 1" seems pretty clear to me. The procedure returns a bigint instead of an int as the first value. This has nothing to do with Go.

Answer (score 0):

Your statement after `RETURN QUERY` in the function body is likely selecting an identifier defined as `bigint`/`bigserial` type. It's not always safe to assume that this `bigint` value will map to your output `integer` because `bigint` can accommodate a higher values than `integer` can. From [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-NUMERIC-TABLE):

- `integer` can be anything from -2147483648 to +2147483647
- `bigint` can go from -9223372036854775808 to +9223372036854775807
- `bigserial` can go from +1 to +9223372036854775807

If you stumbled upon a `prod_period_id` of 214748364***8***, you'd get an `ERROR:  integer out of range`. To fix this you need to change the output types of your function accordingly:

```sql
DROP FUNCTION public.sp_production_snapshot(integer,integer);
CREATE FUNCTION public.sp_production_snapshot(
  periodid integer, --should be bigint too if it corresponds to prod_period_id
  flagdc integer) 
RETURNS TABLE(
  prod_period_id bigint,--change from integer to bigint
  period character varying, 
...
```

Depending on the structure of your `RETURN QUERY` and its sources, it's likely that it won't be the only output `integer` value you'll have to change to `bigint`. Note that you'll have to furst `DROP` then re-`CREATE` the function to avoid `ERROR:  cannot change return type of existing function` thrown if you tried `CREATE OR REPLACE` instead.

If your output table follows the structure of some other table, instead of copying that into the function output table definition, you can use `LIKE` syntax:

```sql
DROP FUNCTION public.sp_production_snapshot(integer,integer);
CREATE FUNCTION public.sp_production_snapshot(
  periodid integer, 
  flagdc integer) 
RETURNS TABLE (LIKE your_table_schema.your_table_name) as 
$function$
  ... 
$function$ language plpgsql;
```

or `RETURNS SETOF`:

```sql
DROP FUNCTION public.sp_production_snapshot(integer,integer);
CREATE FUNCTION public.sp_production_snapshot(
  periodid integer, 
  flagdc integer) 
RETURNS SETOF your_table_schema.your_table_name language plpgsql as 
$function$
  ... 
$function$;
```

Also, if all you do is return a query, without using [PL/pgSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-overview.html) variables, loops, exception handling, you can stick with plain [`LANGUAGE SQL`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-sql.html) for better performance thanks to [inlining](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Inlining_of_SQL_functions). If all it does is look things up elsewhere, without modifying anything, it might be worth it to also make it [`STABLE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-volatility.html) and [`PARALLEL SAFE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/sql-createfunction.html#:%7E:text=parallel%20unsafe%20if%20they%20modify) to enable better optimisation and execution planning.

```
DROP FUNCTION public.sp_production_snapshot(integer,integer);
CREATE FUNCTION public.sp_production_snapshot(
  periodid integer, 
  flagdc integer) 
RETURNS SETOF your_table_schema.your_table_name 
STABLE PARALLEL SAFE LANGUAGE SQL AS 
$function$
  SELECT * FROM your_table_schema.your_table_name AS a
  WHERE a.prod_period_id = $1 AND a.flagdc = $2;
$function$;
```